# Newly added DOM element returns null

Tags: javascript, dom, tinymce, getelementbyid

I am adding a span to a tinymce document at run time.

```
ed.onKeyUp.add(function (ed, e) {
   sendText(ed, e);
   ed = tinyMCE.get('editor');
   range = ed.selection.getRng();

   var newNode = ed.getDoc().createElement("span");
   newNode.id = "caret";
   ed.getDoc().body.appendChild(newNode);

   newNode.innerHTML = "|";
   newNode.style.color = "black";
   range.insertNode(newNode);
});
```

As you can see I am adding the node by using the createElement method and also adding it to the DOM by using append child to my desired element.

The problem is that I can't find the newly added element by using:

```
document.getElementById("caret");
```

It is returning null. Why is this happening? Any idea what I can do?

**EDIT**: I am using document.getElementById("caret"); in a function which I call upon initializing the tinyMCE document since I need this function for blinking a custom caret.

This is the function:

```
function blink() {
        var caret = document.getElementById("caret");

        if (caret.style.color == "transparent") {
            caret.style.color = "black"
        } else {
            caret.style.color = "transparent";
        }
    }
```

and I'm calling it oninit: setInterval("blink()", 700) where oninit is a parameter for tinyMCE.

Comment: Are you calling `document.getElementById("caret")` *after* you inserted the node? Does `ed.getDoc().getElementById("caret")` work?

Comment: I don't recognize some of this (`ed.onKeyUp.add`, `ed.getDoc()`...).  Are you using a JavaScript library of some kind?

Comment: @scott.korin: It's TinyMCE

Comment: I guess she is using TinyMCE

Comment: yes I'm using tinyMCE.. let me edit the post and show you from where I'm calling getElementByID

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TinyMCE uses an iframe containing its own document to allow editing.

As such, when you use `document.getElementById`, you're searching the wrong DOM.

If you have access to the TinyMCE editor object, you could use `ed.getDoc().getElementById()` instead.

If you need global access, you can use the [`TinyMCE.editors`](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/API3%3aproperty.tinymce.editors) collections to access the specific editor.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! true you have a point! but my blink() function has to be global to be accessible and therefore I don't have access to ed there!